# Pulling data from application life cycle management and sending to sharepoint using python script what procedure has to follow

Tags: python

```
import json
import requests
url='https://<server>:<port>'
shared_space='99999'
workspace='9999'
client_id="ID"
client_secret="SECRET"
HeaderInfo={'Content-Type': 'application/json','ALM_OCTANE_TECH_PREVIEW': 'true'}
```

When connecting to ALM Octane REST API, following parameters need to be defined:

url: The ALM Octane Server URL

shared_space: The ID of the ALM Octane shared space

workspace: The ID of the ALM Octane workspace

client_id and client_secret: The API access key for the authentication to ALM Octane REST API.

Comment: Please change this to remove sensitive info!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.